# How to get LAN and WLAN MAC Address with batchfile?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, computer-name

I've recently been trying to make a batch file that will identify the serial number, WLAN & LAN MAC Address of the of the computer. After retrieving set info, I would like it to rename the computer description in this format: "Serial Number 4444 WLAN 4444 LAN 4444"

The code for the wlan and lan mac address doesn't work and I can't to figure out why.

I tried doing it in powershell and I was successful but I didn't know how to call the variable.

`$var=(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.ipenabled -EQ $true}).Macaddress | select-object -first 1`

```
#!/bin/bash

#Change Name
wmic computersystem where "name='%computername%'" call rename name=Computer2

#Get Serial Number
for /f %%i in ('wmic bios get serialnumber ^|find "M"') do set cereal=%%i
```

```
#Get WLAN MAC Address
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=," %%b in ('getmac /fo csv /v ^| find "Wi-Fi"') do set WLAN=%%~b

#Get LAN MAC Address
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('getmac /fo csv /v ^| find "Ethernet"') do set LAN=%%~a
```

```
#Set the Computer Description Name
set ComputerDes=%cereal% WLAN %WLAN% LAN %LAN%
net config server /srvcomment:"%ComputerDes%"

#Restart the PC
shutdown.exe /r /t 60
```

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` ??????

Comment: Is that not supposed to be there?

Comment: Well no.  You are not using `BASH`. You are using a Windows `.bat` file.  When using the `usebackq` option you need to use the back quote. It literally says that that in the help file.  That is why your `LAN` variables do not get set.

Comment: ``(`getmac /fo csv /v ^| find "Ethernet"`)``?

Comment: Do you know why it keeps looping over and over? @Squashman

Comment: That is a very vague description. You have no loops in your code.

Comment: You didn't name the script the same thing as one of the commands in your script, did you? Maybe getmac?

Comment: Try posting in the bash category instead of batch :)

Comment: @w1ll - but this isn't bash; it's batch with incorrect commenting syntax and an erroneous first line.

Comment: @SomethingDark Youre right on that one, Sherlock.